# How to pass data around after parsing json Objects

Tags: android, json

I am trying to create an app that will organize the COVID-19 information (#death, #inspection, #patiens...etc). I have found a website that is open-source and lets me use the JSON data. So I have parsed them; HOWEVER, I cannot pass the data around the mainActivity so I can create graphs and make calculations outside the method private `jsonParseRequest()`.

This is the entire `jsonParseRequest` method so I can request `json` and parse it.

What I have tried:

- I tried to make the method return the `json` data as string using `Integer.toString() (int ndeaths, int ninspections, int npatients)`
- Creating an `arrayList` making and add those data, but when I try to access it says error `IndexOutOfBounds`.

  ```
  private void jsonParseRequest(){
      final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
      String url = "https://www.stopcovid19.jp/data/covid19japan.json";
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

      final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
          @Override
          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
              try {
                  //Input the jsonObject to String called data
                  String data = response.toString();
                  //Create jsonObject and input the string data inside, so now the string data is converted to jsonObject?

                  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                  //Use json data to extract the data using the key such as "ndeaths"
                  int ndeaths = jsonObject.getInt("ndeaths");
                  int ninspections = jsonObject.getInt("ninspections");
                  int npatients = jsonObject.getInt("npatients");
                  String lastUpdate = jsonObject.getString("lastUpdate");

                  //the textView has to be converted to String ot be able to display!!
                  textView.setText("Last Update: " + lastUpdate + "\n" + "Number of deaths: " + Integer.toString(ndeaths) + "\n" + "Number of Inspection: " + Integer.toString(ninspections) + "\n" + "Number of Positives: " + Integer.toString(npatients));



              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              error.printStackTrace();
          }
      });
      queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
  }
  ```

Comment: Sorry, part of the code was sticking out from the box

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value